# What does it mean to “die game”?

Tags: meaning, french-language, translation, the-phantom-of-the-opera, gaston-leroux

In chapter 3 of *The Phantom of the Opera*, it says that the retiring managers had

> determined to “die game”, as we now say.

What does that mean?

I have searched the web with no luck.

Comment: *game* = gamely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the entire sentence from the [English translation on Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Phantom_of_the_Opera/Chapter_III):

> During  this time, the farewell ceremony was taking place. I have already said that this magnificent function was being given on the occasion of the retirement of M. Debienne and M. Poligny, who had determined to **"die game," as we say nowadays**.

Here is the corresponding part in the [French version (on Wikisource)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Fant%C3%B4me_de_l%E2%80%99Op%C3%A9ra/Chapitre_III):

> Pendant ce temps avait lieu la cérémonie des adieux.
>
> J’ai dit que cette fête magnifique avait été donnée, à l’occasion de leur départ de l’Opéra, par MM. Debienne et Poligny qui avaient voulu mourir **comme nous disons aujourd’hui : en beauté.**

One can translate "mourir en beauté" (literally "die in beauty") as "to end on a high note". (Gareth Rees mentioned in a comment that "game" here means [gamely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gamely#Adverb).)

In spite of the fact that Debienne and Poligny are retiring as opera managers,

> Everybody remarked that the retiring managers looked cheerful, as is the Paris way. None will ever be a true Parisian who has not learned to wear a mask of gaiety over his sorrows and one of sadness, boredom or indifference over his inward joy.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I think it would have made more sense to have translated it “die in beauty”. Alas, there is always something I miss when having to read translations. Thank you!